# Function table() : is it possible to keep all the modality?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I use the classic function table().

If I have a variable with four modalities and one of them has no occurrence, then it does not appear in the table() R output. Is it possible to display it with the number of occurrences written in below "0"? Here is an illustrated example:

I have this dataframe for example :

| id | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blue |
| 2 | red |
| 3 | white |
| 4 | red |

If i do the table() function, I have :

| blue | red | white |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |

But in my case, my variable "Color" have four modalities : "blue", "red", "white" and "black". Therefore, I would like to have in output with the function table (or another function) :

| blue | red | white | black |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With table this is to the best I know not possible directly.

But we can do the following:
We can transform `Color` to factor and indicate all occurring levels also those with 0:

```
df$Color <- factor(df$Color, levels = c("blue", "red", "white", "black"))
table(df$Color)
```

```
 blue   red white black 
    1     2     1     0
```